# I'm using Mysql, Engine's InnoDB. But "doesn't exist in engine" is happend

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm using my DB is made of InnoDB engine.
Suddenly, "doesn't exist in engine" message comes out and can not run any query on DB.

So, I checked on MySQL command window like below.

[image]

Like picture which is above said(Highlighted Yellow), Engine is NULL.

But, you can see all tables in my DB are mapped with InnoDB as below.

[image]

How can I map engine(InnoDB) to my tables?

`Alter Table [table_name] Engine = InnoDB` does not work.

Comment: Look in your mysql error log and show the output (as text)

Comment: Execute `SHOW ENGINES`. Is it in your supported list?

Comment: This is usually a sign that the files on your harddrive got corrupted/deleted/cannot be accessed/... Check and/or recall if you did something to/in the data folder.